# Bibliography Issue apacite: Argument of \@@cite has an extra }

Tags: bibliographies, citing, apa-style

I am having an issue when citing references within my thesis. I use the `apacite` package. Below is the basic structure of the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Literature Review}
Several methodological challenges arise when modeling count data (see 
\cite{lord_statistical_2010} for a good review).

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

This is the entry in the .bib file:

```
@article{lord_statistical_2010,
title = {The statistical analysis of crash-frequency data: A review and 
      assessment of methodological alternatives},
volume = {44},
issn = {09658564},
shorttitle = {The statistical analysis of crash-frequency data},
url = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0965856410000376},
doi = {10.1016/j.tra.2010.02.001},
number = {5},
journal = {Transportation Research Part A: Policy and Practice},
author = {Lord, Dominique and Mannering, Fred},
month = jun,
year = {2010},
pages = {291--305}
    }
```

However when I run the `PDFLaTeX` I get the following error:

```
error: line 0 : Argument of \@@cite has an extra }
```

I generate the `references.bib` file using Zotero software. I very recently changed the package style to `apacite`. Previously I had used `\bibliographystyle{plain}` and the references had generated as desired. But now I have hit this roadblock.

I am now clueless as to why this is happening. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show the entry `lord_statistical_2010` of your bib file. Which document class do you use?. It's always the best providing a complete working minimal example.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get any error.

Comment: When switching from one bibliography style to another, and especially when switching from one citation package to another (such as apacite), it's a good idea to wipe out all `.aux`, `.bbl`, and similar files and recompile the file from scratch, lest LaTeX and/or BibTeX get confused.

Comment: Your example does not give an error. Most likely you are loading the package `apacite` before `hyperref`. `apacite` is one of the exceptional packages that has to load `hyperref` first.

Comment: @strpeter I had the same problem with the OP and your comment fixed it. Thank you. The question shouldn't be closed.

Comment: @Aventinus: You had a problem compiling the exact code from above? Then state your OS and the version of latex you are using (as Kurt asked above) such that it can get reproducible.

Comment: @Mico s answer fixed it for me! Same error after an internal update of the zotero extension!