# Hyperlinks for in-text citations

Tags: hyperref, packages, hyperlink

I have been trying to activate the hyperlinks of my in-text citations, but each way I try it out, it is not produced successfully. One way led to in-text citations in hyperlinks but with years of cited works missing. Below I show my loaded packages in my current version before adding hyperlinks. I would appreciate your advice on how to do it correctly. Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs,xltabular}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[margin=100pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subfig}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand{\etal}{\textit{et al.}}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{datetime2}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[font=large,labelfont=bf]{caption} % Required for specifying captions to tables and figures

%\captionsetup{justification   = raggedright,
 %             singlelinecheck = false}
\renewcommand{\today}{\ifcase \month \or January\or February\or March\or %
April\or May \or June\or July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or %
December\fi, \number \year} 



\title{Manuscript}
\author{X 
}
 

\begin{document}
\date{\monthyeardate}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\maketitle


\begin{abstract}

\shortcite{Degen_2018}

\end{abstract}

\newpage
\section{Introduction}


\bibliography{references.bib} 
\bibliographystyle{elsevier} 
\end{document}
```

The referrenced bib:

```
@article{Degen_2018,
    doi = {10.1177/0958928718781293      },
    year = 2018,
    publisher = {{SAGE} Publications},
    volume = {29},
    number = {2},
    pages = {148--165},
    author = {Daniel Degen and Theresa Kuhn and Wouter van der Brug},
    title = {Granting immigrants access to social benefits? How self-interest influences support for welfare state restrictiveness},
    journal = {Journal of European Social Policy}
}
```

Comment: Is Biblatex an option? It has support out of the box.

Comment: I am not sure I get what you mean.

Comment: you are not loading hyperref, so you don't have links at all. Beside this your example doesn't contain any citation, so can't be used to test your problem.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I was mentioning above that I removed the hyperlink work package to see if any of the loaded ones conflict with it. Now I have added it along with the citation. The year does not appear.

Comment: Okay, thank you all. Thanks for the edits, Ulrike. I just found out the answer in another post that apacite is one of the exceptional packages that has to load hyperref first. (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68698/bibliography-issue-apacite-argument-of-cite-has-an-extra)